# How can I load pre-computed Google Earth Engine datasets into the stand-alone Google Earth client?

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-engine

The [Google Earth Engine website](https://earthengine.google.org/) lists a number of featured datasets.  When I click on one of the time lapse datasets, it opens in my browser (Firefox on Linux), but for the "Precomputed datasets", I get "The Google Earth Plugin is currently only available on Windows and Mac OS X 10.6+.".  That's okay, I have the standalone client.  But do I load the examples listed on the website — in particular, the two Global Roadless Area datasets — into the stand-alone Google Earth client?

Comment: FYI, see http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3490/where-should-google-earth-questions-really-be It's not an answer to your question, but...

Comment: @martinf As far as I can tell, based on the meta post, I'm on the right site (my question is not a programming one, but purely from the perspective of an end user)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Precomputed datasets" can be loaded into the Google Earth standalone client as follows:

1. View the source of the Earth Engine webpage (https://earthengine.google.org/#intro)
2. Search for the galleryMetadata object, which is a list of dataset definitions. Within the galleryMetadate object, the "Precomputed datasets" will have a attribute named "kml" whose value is the URL of the dataset. Copy the URL. For example: http://mw1.google.com/ges/gallery/roadless.1km/root.kmz
3. Open up the Google Earth standalone client
4. Select Add -> Network link, paste the URL into the "Link:" box, and then click OK